# How to use Regex.Split on this String?

Tags: .net, regex, split

Does anyone know how to write a Regex.Split in order to convert

**{video="my/video/file.flv,my/location.jpg"}**

into

1. my/video/file.flv
2. my/location.jpg

Comment: If you allow any of your paths to contain commas (which is an allowed character under Windows), this is an impossible problem unless each path is separated in some other way.

Comment: None of the paths will ever contain commas.

Comment: How 'bout a combination of `IndexOf('\"')` and `LastIndexOf('\"')` and then `Split(',')` instead?  I can quarantee this would be both easier to maintain and faster.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This work around seems to have done the trick for me.  Thoughts?

```
    Dim str As String = "this is exciting {video=""my/exciting/video.flv,my/refreshing/image.jpg""} this is refreshing"
    Dim regFind As String = "(?'text'\{video=""(.*)\""})"
    Dim matcher As Match = Regex.Match(str, regFind)

    Dim Matched As String() = (matcher.Groups("text").Value).Split(",")

    Dim video As String = Matched(0).Replace("{video=""", "")
    Dim jpg As String = Matched(1).Replace("""}", "")

    Response.Write(video)
    Response.Write("<br />")
    Response.Write(jpg)
```

Answer (score 1):

Like this:

```
new Regex(@"[{="",}]").Split(@"{video=""my/video/file.flv,my/location.jpg}").Where(s => s.Length > 0)
```

**EDIT**: In VB:

```
Dim regex As New Regex("[{="",}]")
Dim myStr = "{video=""my/video/file.flv,my/location.jpg}"

Dim results = regex.Split(myStr).Where(Function(s) s.Length > 0)
```

Comment: thanks, but how would that work with a dynamic flv and a dynamic jpg?

Comment: also, I tried the Telerik Converter but got a syntax error.  Any chance you have some VB knowledge?

Comment: What do you mean by a dynamic flv and a dynamic jpg?  You can put any string you want into the `Split` call.

Comment: it's going in a content management system.  So basically they will put in {video="new/other/video.flv,a/different/image.jpg"}. What I want to do is replace the entire string with a JWPlayer oject that will play the video they tell it to.

Comment: @SLaks: I think you're missing the closing quote in the input string.

Comment: ...and this also returns the token "video" in the returned string array.

Comment: I can see how this would work if I hardcode the flv file path and the jpg file path, however I don't see how I would do it when the flv file path and jpg file path are changing.

Comment: @Jon: I answered this before he edited the question.  @Rock: You can use any string you want.

Comment: I'm getting an error above.  "Where is not a member of System.Array"

Answer (score 0):

Have you considered using the Split function?

```
string x  = "{video=\"my/video/file.flv,my/location.jpg\"}";
string xx = x.Split(',');
```

Comment: It needs to be a regex match because the "my/video/file.flv" and the "my/location.jpg" will always be changing.